# Explode Deeply Nested JSON returning duplicates in Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, explode

I have a utility which is working fine for parsing simple JSONs, but cross joining in case multiple array[structs] is present in the JSON

I have tried distinct() or dropDuplicates() as well to remove duplicates which is happening due to the cross join that I have included in the code, but thats returning empty DF..

```
def flattenDataFrame(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

var flattenedDf: DataFrame = df
if (isNested(df)) {
  val flattenedSchema: Array[(Column, Boolean)] = flattenSchema(df.schema)
  var simpleColumns: List[Column] = List.empty[Column]
  var complexColumns: List[Column] = List.empty[Column]

  flattenedSchema.foreach {
    case (col, isComplex) => {
      if (isComplex) {
        complexColumns = complexColumns :+ col
      } else {
        simpleColumns = simpleColumns :+ col
      }
    }
  }

  var crossJoinedDataFrame = df.select(simpleColumns: _*)
  complexColumns.foreach(col => {
    crossJoinedDataFrame = crossJoinedDataFrame.crossJoin(df.select(col))
    crossJoinedDataFrame = flattenDataFrame(crossJoinedDataFrame)
  })
  crossJoinedDataFrame
} else {
  flattenedDf
}
  }

private def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null): Array[(Column, Boolean)] = {

schema.fields.flatMap(field => {

  val columnName = if (prefix == null) field.name else prefix + "." + field.name
  field.dataType match {
    case arrayType: ArrayType => {
      val cols: Array[(Column, Boolean)] = Array[(Column, Boolean)](((explode_outer(col(columnName)).as(columnName.replace(".", "_"))), true))
      cols
      }
    case structType: StructType => {
      flattenSchema(structType, columnName)
    }
    case _ => {
      val columnNameWithUnderscores = columnName.replace(".", "_")
      val metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putString("encoding", "ZSTD").build()
      Array(((col(columnName).as(columnNameWithUnderscores, metadata)), false))
    }
  }
}).filter(field => field != None)
}

def isNested(df: DataFrame): Boolean = {
df.schema.fields.flatMap(field => {
  field.dataType match {
    case arrayType: ArrayType => {
      Array(true)
    }
    case mapType: MapType => {
      Array(true)
    }
    case structType: StructType => {
      Array(true)
    }
    case _ => {
      Array(false)
    }
  }
}).exists(b => b)
}
```

A sample JSON in which I am facing the issue:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Raised",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without join and more than that, no cross-join which is your problem:

Sorry for the formatting, can't really get it to format well for stack-overflow

```
def flattenDataFrame(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
```

```
val flattenedDf: DataFrame = df

if (isNested(df)) {
  val flattenedSchema: Array[(Column, Boolean)] = flattenSchema(flattenedDf.schema)

  var simpleColumns: List[Column] = List.empty[Column]
  var complexColumns: List[Column] = List.empty[Column]

  flattenedSchema.foreach {
    case (col, isComplex) =>
      if (isComplex) {
        complexColumns = complexColumns :+ col
      } else {
        simpleColumns = simpleColumns :+ col
      }
  }

  val complexUnderlyingCols = complexColumns.map { column =>
    val name = column.expr.asInstanceOf[UnresolvedAttribute].name
    val unquotedColName = s"${name.replaceAll("`","")}"
    val explodeSelectColName = s"`${name.replaceAll("`","")}`"
    (unquotedColName, col(name).as(unquotedColName), explode_outer(col(explodeSelectColName)).as(unquotedColName))
  }

  var joinDataFrame = flattenedDf.select(simpleColumns ++ complexUnderlyingCols.map(_._2): _*)

  complexUnderlyingCols.foreach { case (name, tempCol, column) =>
    val nonTransformedColumns = joinDataFrame.schema.fieldNames.diff(List(name)).map(fieldName => s"`${fieldName.replaceAll("`", "")}`").map(col)
    joinDataFrame = joinDataFrame.select(nonTransformedColumns :+ column :_*)
  }
  flattenDataFrame(joinDataFrame)
} else {
  flattenedDf
}
```

}

private def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null, level: Int = 0): Array[(Column, Boolean)] = {
    val unquotedPrefix = if (prefix != null) prefix.replace("`", "") else null
    println(level)
    schema.fields.flatMap(field => {
      val fieldName = field.name
      val columnName = if (level == 0) {
        s"`$fieldName`"
      } else {
        val fullName = s"$unquotedPrefix.$fieldName"
        val x = fullName.split('.').reverse.zipWithIndex.reverse.foldLeft(new StringBuilder("`")){ case (builder, (fieldPart, index)) =>
            if(index > level) {
              builder.append(s".$fieldPart")
            } else if (index == level) {
              builder.append(s".$fieldPart`")
            } else {
              builder.append(s".$fieldPart")
            }
        }
        x.replace(1,2,"").toString()
      }
      val unquotedColumnName = columnName.replace("`", "")
      field.dataType match {
        case _: ArrayType =>
          val cols: Array[(Column, Boolean)] = Array[(Column, Boolean)]((col(columnName), true)) // We pass only the column as we'll generate explode function while expanding the DF
          cols
        case structType: StructType =>
          flattenSchema(structType, columnName, level + 1)
        case _ =>
          val metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putString("encoding", "ZSTD").build()
          Array((col(columnName).as(unquotedColumnName, metadata), false))
      }
    })
  }

def isNested(df: DataFrame): Boolean = {
    df.schema.fields.flatMap(field => {

`field.dataType match {
    case _: ArrayType =>
      Array(x = true)
    case _: MapType =>
      Array(x = true)
    case _: StructType =>
      Array(x = true)
    case _ =>
      Array(x = false)
  }
}).exists(b => b)
}`